# Combining same key's in an array and print it in smarty

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop, smarty

I have `$product.features` array in PrestaShop 1.7.

Here is the sample data in the array. `$product.features.name: $product.features.value`

```
width: 100 m
method: Nail Down
method: Main Floor
Warranty: 25 years
Color: Red
Color: Blue
```

**I want to print the above data as**

```
Width: 100m
method: Nail Down, Main Floor
Warranty: 25 years
Color: Red, Blue
```

**Here is the smarty code i have**

```
{foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="name">{$feature.name}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="value flex_child">{$feature.value}</div>
    </div>         
 {/foreach}
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: You could change the structure of the features array and then loop the array where the key is what comes before the `:` and the value is what comes after it https://3v4l.org/4dmsO

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="name">{$feature.name}: {$feature.value}</div>
    </div>         
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to prepare the features array for looping the keys and values.

For example, using [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to return an array where the keys are the part before the `:` and the values are the imploded result with `,` as the delimiter:

```
$features = [
    "width with: 100 m",
    "method: Nail Down",
    "method: Main Floor",
    "Warranty: 25 years",
    "Color: Red",
    "Color: Blue"
];

$features = array_reduce($features, function($carry, $item){
    $parts = explode(":", $item);
    $carry[$parts[0]][] = $parts[1];
    return $carry;
});

foreach ($features as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: " . implode(',', $value) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
width:  100 m
method:  Nail Down, Main Floor
Warranty:  25 years
Color:  Red, Blue
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/WoAdp)